# Flagging a comment temporarily hides the upvote button/indication

Tags: bug, comments, design, comment-flags, comment-voting

After flagging a comment, the upvote button/indicator will disappear, until you reload the page. Here is an example where I already upvoted the post (and the upvote button is visible in a 'permanently active' state):

[image: GIF of an upvoted comment being flagged, which makes the upvote indicator disappear]

but it also disappears if you didn't upvote the comment.

Comment: Here's a comment for y'all to test - don't forget to retract the flag after you've confirmed the behaviour :)

Comment: Why would you want to be able to upvote a comment you've just flagged?

Comment: Flagging a comment that you haven't upvoted doesn't allow you to upvote it subsequently. Isn't this how it has always been?

Comment: I don't want to upvote it (I've already done that), it's just strange (and a fairly recent change) that the indication disappears and only reappears when you reload the page.

Comment: You also cannot unupvote the comment after flagging and retracting the flag.

Comment: @AndrewLeach consider the opposite scenario - you've already upvoted it (because you misclicked when trying to hit the flag icon) and you want to unupvote it. If you have already flagged, then *you cannot unupvote*. Flagging removes the upvote icon (which you need to click to retract) and reloading the page restores the upvote icon but removes the ability to retract. Either this is not by design or the design is broken. This would be a bug in either case.

Comment: For what it's worth, this just seems like a silly client side issue. SE APIs still allow undoing an upvote after flagging a comment, I just tested and I was able to manually remove my upvote through `curl` after flagging a comment above.